# Concatenating reference with formula gives runtime error

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to use VBA to concatenate a string inside a formula. If I only use the code below i'm not getting any errors but when i add the IFERROR together with the code I get a runtime error.

Is there any way to work around it?

```
text1 = "='C:\Users\JOHLA\\Desktop\Yield ark\Nyt-yield-ark\[Yield-Uge-"
text2 = ".xlsm]Scrap'!H7"
```

The code including string with IFERROR that gives runtime error is given below.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim preRange As Range
Dim path, filename1 As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set preRange = ws.Range("E9:I17")
i = ws.Range("C1").Value
text1 = "=IFERROR('C:\Users\JOHLA\Desktop\Yield ark\Nyt-yield-ark\[Yield-Uge-"
text2 = ".xlsm]Scrap'!H7;0)"

With ws
    For i = .Range("C1").Value To .Range("C1").Value + 4
        debug.print text1 & i & text2
        preRange = text1 & i & text2
        Set preRange = preRange.Offset(0, 5)
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Debug this code `text1 & i & text2` you'll see there are many errors such as you have `J0HLA\\Desktop` when it should be `J0HLA\Desktop` and your `IFERROR` ends like `;")`

Comment: Note that quotation marks in formulas in VBA should be doubled. E.g. `"=IF(A1=2,"","OK")"` should be `"=IF(A1=2,"""",""OK"")"`

Comment: I've updated the code, but still getting runtime error "1004". Tim Stack the syntax should be alright. If i write i manually the error doesn't occur.
I can copy the print from my debug and then it works.

Comment: Have you tried `preRange.Formula1:= text1 & i & text2`?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure for formula1 is supposed to work? The description on the function is very vague.

Comment: Should be `Formula`, I mistakenly typed `Formula1` which is for `CF`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your use of semicolon in your formula, it would suggest that you're using local settings which are not compatible with VBA.Formula

in this case, you either need to change the formula to use a comma or set the formula using `FormulaLocal`:

```
preRange.FormulaLocal = Replace(text1 & i & text2, "'", Chr(34))
```

As you can see, I've also added a `Replace` that changes `'` into `"` - as I think you need this also.

Lastly, don't forget to enable `ScreenUpdating` and `DisplayAlerts` at the end of your routine.

Comment: FormulaLocal was the final piece to the puzzle!

I'm referencing to a cell in another closed workbook and that's why the " ' " is in both endes of the filepath.  
This is just a codesnippet so i've got screenUpdating and DisplayAlerts futher down.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out.

Comment: Make sure that you're using good error handling around those ScreenUpdating and DisplayAlerts calls.  If you aren't making sure that you always reset them, an error in your code will leave Excel in a really bad state.

Comment: @FrankBall I'm new at programming, but could it be solved by a  IF statement where i check if it is true or false?

Comment: No need for an `If` really. If you decide to add an error trap to your code, just set them to `True`. If they're `True` already, there's no harm.

Comment: Any time you use Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Answer (score 0):

Any time you use

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

you need to make sure that you are using error handling to manage if your code breaks.

```
On Error GoTo ExitErr

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   <your code here>

ExitErr:
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

This makes sure that if your code breaks (in your case the most obvious being someone renaming "Sheet1"), Excel isn't left with ScreenUpdating and DisplayAlerts left turned off.  I can't tell you how many times I've had to fix other people's code because they turned off these functions and then couldn't figure out why Excel was acting up.

Comment: You're setting them to `False` in your `ExitErr`..? I think you mean `True`?